# How to send RequestHeader to ServiceCall?

Tags: scala, lagom

I have my Asset api and asset impl in lagom. I want to send headers from another service booking impl. I did it by using "handleRequestHeader". I am writing the test cases for booking and unable to send headers in test cases.

AssetService- api

```
def getAsset(assetID: String): ServiceCall[NotUsed, GetAssetResponse]
AssetService-impl
override def getAsset(assetID: String): ServerServiceCall[NotUsed, GetAssetResponse] = ServerServiceCall
```

Could anyone help me in how to send requsetheaders to the Asset from Booking in test cases?

I have tried using,

```
Mockito.when(assetService.getAsset(ValidAssetID)
        .handleRequestHeader(request => request.withHeader(HeaderName, booking.user.id)).invoke())
        .thenReturn(Future.successful(assetResponse))
```